# Insecure world writable dir /usr in PATH, mode 040777

Tags: node.js, heroku

I am trying to set up a node.js application on Heroku and I am following the instructions on https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-nodejs#prerequisites.

When I push the application to Heroku with the command "git push heroku master" I get the error message:
Insecure world writable dir /usr in PATH, mode 040777

I have checked the numerous posts about this problem, all of which seem to recommend running the command sudo chmod -R o-w /usr/local/ (and variations thereof). However, doing so does not help.

Answer (score 1):

Your error lies in /usr. try the following command instead.
chmod o-w /usr
This should fix it.

Answer (score 0):

This command should resolve your problem: `chmod go-w {/path/of/user}`

In the command that you attempted it seems as though you did not effect the group